# ¿como actualizar fecha de una columna en mysql pero sin afectar la hora?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy tratando de actualizar un campo en mi base de datos el cual contiene fecha y hora pero solo debo cambiar la fecha y dejar la hora intacta, hay alguna forma de hacer esto? la estructura de la columna es asi.
"2019-01-24 12:00"
y quiero poder actualizarla para que solo cambie la fecha asi
"2019-01-25 12:00" por ejemplo, el tipo de campo es timestamp, no se si influya. cualquier informacion la agradesco mucho, incluso si al final es imposible agradezco que me lo hagan saber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el CONCAT y el TIME para conservar la hora

```
UPDATE Test SET fecha = concat('2011-01-12 ', time(fecha));
```